# Is there an equivalent for "tiervenner" in English or other languages?

Tags: primary-education, terminology, language-use

In Norway a widely used concept is that of "tiervenner", "ten friends" (my translation to Finnish is "kymppikaverit"). This simply means numbers (implicitly positive integers) whose sum is ten. There are some resources that name this in Danish, too.

Is a similar term used in other languages? Or, in the absence of such a term, is the concept in use when introducing numbers and simple arithmetic to children?

Comment: Educators talk about "ten bonds" sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen the phrase "make a ten" in wide circulation.  Example:

https://www.mathcoachscorner.com/2020/11/make-a-ten-strategy-for-addition/

Answer (score 1):

In German, the word is "Zehnerzerlegung".

Comment: I am a mathematician and German is my mothertongue. I would not know what a "Zehnerzerlegung" is.

Comment: This answer could be improved by a citation or link to a source that shows how the word can be used in the primary school context in German.